# Firefox middle click to open history menu item in new tab

Tags: firefox, mouse, history, osx-leopard

I recently upgraded to Firefox 7. Occasionally I use middle-click a the History menu item to open it in a new tab, but it opened in the current tab instead. Unfortunately I don't remember which version I last tried it on. After running FF 7 for a while, I ran FF 6.0.2 again, and it also lacked the behavior. Either it never worked in FF6, or FF7 installed a new setting that affected FF6.

Does anyone remember the middle-click to open history menu item in new tab?
Same goes for middle click to open bookmark menu item in new tab - doesn't work anymore.

Note that the lost feature only applies to click on menu items; new tabs do open if I actually use the separate history/bookmarks window ("show all history" or "show all bookmarks").

I'm on Mac OS X Leopard.

**UPDATE:**
This [bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=562154) says that it hasn't been working since FF 3.6 . I guess it's possible I haven't used the feature since then...

Comment: Still working normally for me under Windows 7, so this is either OSX specific or some other kind of bug.

Comment: This is odd. I tried FF 5 with a new profile (no addons) and it still doesn't work. I'm pretty sure it was working back then. I wonder if something changed in the OS itself.

Comment: works for me on Firefox 7 - Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tab Mix Plus plugin should give that functionality. It allows a pretty granular level of control over which buttons do what when clicked where. A lot of their functions have been rolled into the FF tabs over time.

Tab Mix Plus can be added from the Add-Ons section in FF.

Comment: I'm accepting this. However the plugin solves the problem in a non-ideal way (at least on my Mac). Seems that either the OS or Firefox always registers a left-click, no matter what button is clicked, on a History menu item. The plugin has the option to always open a new tab from the History menu, but it also prevents me from opening the item in the current tab using a different button. Also, there are way too many options... unless I read them all, I could be getting other features I don't want. (Before telling me to tweak my options, please try it on a Mac first.)

Comment: TMP is certainly a little bit of "death by options", I agree. I tried TMP lite recently to see if it would give me just the options I want. It did not and so I'm back with the full-featured version. And as I don't have a Mac or have access to a Mac, I can't try it on a Mac and so will refrain from telling you to tweak your options. Is the History windows the only part of FF that doesn't take anything besides left-clicks?

Comment: The history/bookmarks **windows** work just fine. It's the history/bookmarks **menu** that only register a left-click - the roughly-equivalent menu concept on Windows is the one you can access by pressing Alt, usually right below the titlebar.